# В виртуальном терминале кириллица отображается квадратиками

Tags: linux

Захожу в виртуальный терминал через `ctrl+alt+f2`, прописывая `ls`, и у тех каталогов, которые названы на русском языке, имена отображаются квадратиками.

Как исправить это?

вот что выводит после команды `locale`:

```
$ locale
LANG=ru_RU.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

Comment: что показывает `locale`?

Comment: @Nick Volynkin♦ В терменал команду ввести?

Comment: Да, выполните в терминале `locale`.

Comment: @Nick Volynkin♦ через 5 часов отвечу (не дома)

Comment: @NickVolynkin обновил

Comment: https://forum.manjaro.org/t/topic/6816 // текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Comment: @alexanderbarakin я просто на linux mint сижу и решил на arch перейти и эта фотография с виртуалки. и поэтому не смог скопировать нормально.

Comment: консольный шрифт не загружен

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ответ на мой вопрос дал alexander barakin в комментариях.

И когда я решил решил проблему, то мои действия были такие:

1. Установил шрифт Terminus из репозитория.
2. Через sudo открыл фаил vconsole.conf при помощи vim, который находится в папке etc.

   ```
    cd /etc
    sudo vim vconsole.conf
   ```
3. Отредактировал файл так:

   ```
    LOCALE="ru_RU.UTF-8"
    KEYMAP="ru"
    FONT="ter-v16v"
    CONSOLEMAP=""
   ```
4. Сохранил изменения и перезагрузил компьютер.

Тема закрыта.

Answer (score 2):

В иных дистрибутивах может быть полезной команда **setupcon** из пакета [console-setup](http://packages.ubuntu.com/console-setup), которая загрузит доступные шрифты в соответствии с заданной конфигурацией (`/etc/default/console-setup` или `~/.console-setup`). Задать настройки терминала при загрузке можно командой

```
LANG=C sudo dpkg-reconfigure console-setup
```

Более подробное описание в страницах руководства [**setupcon**(1)](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/setupcon.1.html) и [**console-setup**(5)](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/console-setup.5.html).